# racing post web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to Python and web scraping. I want to scrape the racing post site to get the daily races and the stats for each race.

I'm trying to get all the partial links for the races to use later to extract the stats for that race. (http://betting.racingpost.com/horses/cards/)

Example:
[32Red.com Fillies´ Handicap 1m1y](/horses/cards/card.sd?race_id=643822&r_date=2016-03-04)

I'm using this code, but I get all links in the page. I need to locate the extraction data, but I have no clue how to do that. I have tried several approaches but I didn't got the expected results.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://betting.racingpost.com/horses/cards/")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
namelist=bsObj.select("a")
for i in namelist:
    print(i['href'])
```

Comment: Racing post doesn't load content until after the page loads, so you'll have to use something like Selenium to view the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want the links in the table's third column, right?

What would work for that is changing the select and loop to

```
rows = bsObj.select("div#race_result tr")
for row in rows:
    print(row.select("td:nth-of-type(4)"))
```

Unfortunately, there is no class on the column but this should be safe enough with the structure you have.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I m very new to python and i'm trying to learn by myself, but many times i get blocked. 
The idea relative to my question is grab the relative links and use them to scrap the correspondent pages.

For the main link, "http://betting.racingpost.com/horses/cards/" add the relative link "card.sd?race_id=643937&amp;r_date=2016-03-06" to scrap that page.

Comment: @lubinho how did you get on? I'm interested in doing the same thing - i havent started yet but have an understanding of python

Comment: The new comment drew my attention back to this. It sounds like you want to build a proper web scraper which scrapes a whole site. Have you looked at [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)?